# 'Search in All' usando LinqJs

Tags: javascript, array

Estou usando o **[linqJs](https://github.com/neuecc/linq.js)**

Quando tento pegar o id `5512` ele retorna `null`, mas quando pego o `124`, funciona.

```
$.Enumerable.From(structure).Where("$.id==5512").ToArray();
```

Estrutura de objeto:

```
[{
    "id": 124,
    "text": "Pai",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 5511,
        "text": "Filho 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 5512,
        "text": "Filho 2"
      }
    ]
}]
```

Como faço para procurar o ID independente da posição que ele esteja? Nesse caso o 5512

> Imagino que talvez poderia fazer `$.children.id` mas o array é dinâmico então não
>   tenho como saber a posição exata, por isso gostaria de procurar em todos `id`

Answer (score 3):

Você não consegue acessar porque o item com o ID 5512 está em uma lista dentro de uma lista, ou seja, ao fazer `.Where("$.id==5512")` você está buscando somente nos elementos pai e não em `children`.

Para fazer o que você deseja, você pode utilizar o `.SelectMany()` e após isso, selecionar por ID. Veja este exemplo abaixo que acho que você entenderá melhor.

```js
var lista = [{
  "id": 124,
  "text": "Pai",
  "children": [{
      "id": 5511,
      "text": "Filho 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 5512,
      "text": "Filho 2"
    }
  ]
}];

var item = Enumerable.From(lista)
                     .SelectMany("$.children")
                     .Where("$.id==5512")
                     .ToArray();

console.log(item);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```